# loop an image in CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am trying to make an animation in javascript, where as the character is running, the grond should move as well. The problem that I have is that the ground image has an animation, but the image gets cut, and reapear.
[image: ground does not coninues]

I have this piece of code in css

```
.ground {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
animation: ground-animation 20s infinite linear;
```

}

```
@keyframes ground-animation {
from {
    right: -80px;
}

to {
    right: 100%;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using the `background-repeat` property? Like: `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please show us a bit more code - preferably create a runnable snippet - in particulary what HTML has class ground. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Just double the width of ground and repeat background image. No?
https://codepen.io/ildar-meyker/pen/eYrdZyw

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: ground-animation 20s infinite linear;
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/1a/b8/8f1ab8b14a55720d6859620a6f596933.jpg) repeat-x 0 100%;
  background-size: 50% auto;
}

@keyframes ground-animation {
from {
  
}

to {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: At the time your question solely consisted of a single line of text, hence the downvote. I've removed it.